# Create a 5 x 5 matrix of all pair values coming from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey guys so I am trying to create a 5x5 matrix where all the values should be pair numbers. Everything goes well in like the first two tries, it actually prints

```
2 4 6 8 10
12 14 16 18 20
```

but then it becomes

```
16 18 20 22 24
20 22 24 26 28
```

I used the debugger and it turns out that my aux is 15 when j reaches 20, and since j = aux, then j goes back, and that's causing the issue, how do I increment aux so that this issue does not occur?

```
function matrix(array) {
    const row = 5
    let column = 5
    let aux = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        const newArray = []
        for (let j = aux; j < column + aux; j++) {
            if (newArray.length < 5) {
                if (array[j] % 2 == 0) {
                    newArray.push(array[j])
                    console.log(array[j])
                }
                else {
                    column++
                }
            }
            aux = column
        }
    }
}
matrix([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50])
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I want something like:
2 4 6 8 10 -> first row/column
12 14 16 18 20 -> 2nd row/column
22 24 26 28 30 -> 3rd row/column
32 34 36 38 40 -> 4th row/column
42 44 46 48 50 -> 5th row/column
Since it is supposed to print as 5 x 5

Comment: and by "pair" you mean even numbers? I don't see any pairs in your numbers

Comment: Oh yes, I meant to say even numbers. Thanks for bringing that up that was probably creating confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be over-complicating this slightly.  You can do this without a nested loop, and therefore without the `aux` variable.  You simply need one loop that loops through the array that is passed to the function, like so:

```js
    function matrix(array) {
        var newArray = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                newArray.push(array[i]);
                if(newArray.length==5) {
                    console.log(newArray);
                    newArray = [];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    matrix([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I can't vote yet, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is practically mti2935's answer, just output is formatted as requested.

```js
function matrix(array) {
  const column = 5;
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0, rowArray = []; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!(array[i] % 2))
    {
      rowArray.push(array[i]);
      if (rowArray.length == column) {
        console.log(rowArray.map(a=>(" "+a).substr(-2)).join(" "));
        result.push(rowArray);
        rowArray = [];
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log("result:",matrix([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]));
```